# Get R warnings and errors in english

Tags: r, debugging, localization

I'd like R to show me debug messages in english instead that in my locale (Italian). Having messages in italians makes it difficult to look on the internet for help on debugging. Not to mention that sometimes translations are sloppy at least.

How can revert R to use only the original version of messages and not to translate them?

thanks!

Comment: What platform are you running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to set the "LANGUAGE" environment variable ([see relevant documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Sys.setenv.html)):

```
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE='en')
```

To do this, though, you need to have message translations installed (which I believe are optional on at least some platforms).

Comment: Hi, I am using M1 pro chip on MBP currently, is there any way to set this setting permanently? In windows OS, I can disable message translation when I was installing, but it seems that there is no such options on mac when I was installing.